# Setting internet access to hyper-v network with multiple internet connections

Tags: networking, hyper-v, windows-8

I run few VMs for development purposes on Windows 8 Hyper-V. I'm using a laptop for that purpose.
When I switch locations I switch way of connecting to internet - cable in the office, WiFi at home and USB 3G dongle + VPN when working at customers. I would like to have a single network configuration that automatically gives internet access to VMs no matter which way my host is connected. I also need to communicate host-VMs and VM-VM. That kind of setup was easy in VirtualBox, but I can't find a way to make it work in Hyper-V.

One more thing noteworthy - I'm running Windows 8 emulator on my host (main reason why I keep HyperV) which has a strange tendency of resetting network setup and wrapping all host NICs with HyperV ones.

Answer (score 1):

THis is one of the major shortcomings of Hyper-V. VMware Workstation is able to detect which physical NIC is active and just use that, but Hyper-V isnt. You either need to update your virtual switch to connect through the "active" physical NIC (which is easy enough to do with a script), or create a "mapping" VM, which has multiple Virtual switches connected (one for each physical NIC), and acts as a router for internal VMs. This would give you internet access from the VMs, but would make it difficult to gain access to the VMs from your physical network.

Comment: Where can I find some further info about scripts you mentioned?

Comment: PowerShell, "Set-VMSwitch". Description here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848515.aspx

You would need to run "Set-VMSwitch "MyVMSwitch" -NetAdapterName "MyPhysicalNicName""

Answer (score 1):

> I run few VMs for development purposes on Windows 8

Switch to using WIndows Server, Desktop experience - and then use NIC teaming on the server.